# Should a popup/lightbox close when a user clicks outside of the box?

Tags: popup, lightbox

Currently on our application we have popup/lightboxes that have a close button in the top right corner, and some of the lightboxes have cancel buttons next to the submit button - in the case of a form. We also close the lightbox when a user click outside of the lightbox.

My thinking is we are creating a confusing UX, also adding challenge in programming, by letting the user close the lightbox by clicking outside the lightbox. We want them to make a decision once the box is open.

I want to remove the feature of clicking outside the box to close it, leaving the close icon in the top corner and cancel button. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21998/should-touch-screen-simple-informational-dialogs-have-an-ok-button, http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17617/close-button-vs-cancel-button

Answer (score 9):

It largely depends on what the dialog is doing, but generally **yes, leave as many exit vectors for a modal dialog as possible.** As long as other modal dialogs close with the Escape key and clicking outside the window, people will assume yours will too. Clicking away is a common reaction to "Oh, I didn't mean to do that". Forcing the user to interact with the dialog seems much more risky.

It sounds like you might be trying this solution because this is a form and you don't want users to lose their info if they accidentally click out; instead of disabling click-out-to-close

The rare exception is when the user *really really* shouldn't be able to exit the modal dialog. This should be very rare, but it's appropriate if *not* acting could be very dangerous. That's quite uncommon; usually *doing* something is the dangerous sate, rather than not doing anything. On a related note, with destructive actions it's best to give as many exit vectors as possible.

Comment: Our application has about 10 - 15 situations where the modals ask for information. 5 of these are crucial, whereas the user would be more confused if the box was close unintentionally. What about consistency? Some would close differently than others within our application.

Comment: "you don't want users to lose their info if they accidentally click out; instead of disabling click-out-to-close"… what? Don't leave us hanging!

Comment: For what it's worth, throwing up a JS `confirm("Closing this form will discard the information you've entered")` is a good idea regardless of how the user dismisses the lightbox.

Answer (score 6):

It is faster for the user to close the popup dialog by clicking outside. Outside area has a bigger clicking area than a close button and smaller distance to the cursor/finger ([Fitt's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law)). Since some users may not know that closing outside also dismisses the popup so having a Close button is good as well. I don't really see how ability to easily exit adds confusion.

Answer (score 2):

It depends...

- If the dialog contains user inputs, don't close the dialog on click outside because...

  What happens when the user closes it - are the inputs saved/applied or lost? - The user might end up confused or worried. (Especially if there was a lot of input (what if it was lost) or the user didn't want to keep the input (what if it was saved).)
- If the dialog is a enlarged view from a list, do close the dialog on click outside because...

  The user want to be able to quickly move to another item.

If you do enable clicking outside to close the dialog, leave a margin around it (can be seethrough) were the clicking doesn't close the dialog. - This will help prevent [sausage finger mistakes](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17070/whats-the-term-for-imprecision-in-mouse-and-touchscreen-clicking).

Comment: I like this answer. The question was discovered observing frantic and accidental clicking by users.

Comment: @bweikulrich, with the latest phone models this is even more extreme - there is barely any non-screen area to hold onto, so just holding the phone can press the screen corners.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, In my opinion, their is no need for a user to click outside the box to close it. As a developer i strongly suggest to retain the flow i,e to retain the ability for a user to make a decision.

For example, if a user has something to sign up and he has option to either submit or hit close button, probably he may rethink the option to signup again (ok ,not necessarily) since , he cannot just blindly dismiss the form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should for the sake of user control/freedom, unless there's a cancel button on the modal window. Here's a good article that explains the best practices for modal windows: [Modal Windows Best Practices](http://uxmovement.com/forms/modal-windows-best-practices/)